# After the new version of chrome(108), it adds an extra blank page when printing from my application. How can I remove it?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, version

It works fine on Microsoft edge.

The following worked on one page. However, there is this error in the core of the project.

```
@media print {
    html, body {
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }
}
```

While printing some pages, it does not add a blank page to the last page.

Comment: I have this problem too

Comment: Can you specify from which version you encountered this issue?

Comment: chrome version :108.0.5359.125

Answer (score 5):

Try removing the extra `page-break-after` for the last elements in the DOM.

I changed my css from this

```
    .page {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
```

to this:

```
    .page:not(:last-child) {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
```

Comment: page-break-after is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after

Answer (score 5):

The same behavior is observed when trying to print a Google map.
Workaround is here.
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/191619088?hl=en&msgid=192661374

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after the last chrome update.

I have a multi-page break One after the other, and it prints an n-1 blank page.
For that, I changed my code to hide all page breaks except the first one.

Old Code

```
 div.pagebreak  {
        page-break-before: always !important;
        clear: both !important;
    }
```

new Code

```
div.pagebreak {
    display: none;
}

.single-page+div.pagebreak  {
    break-before: page !important;
    clear: both !important;
    display: block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had already updated the `page-break-after`, which did not do the trick.

What solved this for me (2023, Chrome > v108) was setting the @page size. It used to be `auto` and I set it to the real size of the page.

Both things are in place now, @page size and page-break-after

Docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size